# lighthouse library installation fails in python

Tags: python, installation, lighthouse

When I tried to run the `pip install lighthouse` command in Anaconda Prompt, I got the following result:

```
(base) C:\Users\myuser>pip install lighthouse
Collecting lighthouse
  Using cached lighthouse-1.0.0.tar.gz (36 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: watchdog in c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from lighthouse) (2.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from lighthouse) (6.0)
Collecting kazoo
  Using cached kazoo-2.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from lighthouse) (1.16.0)
Collecting futures
  Using cached futures-3.0.5.tar.gz (25 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [27 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 14, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 247, in <module>
          monkey.patch_all()
        File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 97, in patch_all
          patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler()
        File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 157, in patch_for_msvc_specialized_compiler
          patch_func(*msvc14('_get_vc_env'))
        File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\monkey.py", line 147, in patch_params
          mod = import_module(mod_name)
        File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
          return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 20, in <module>
          import unittest.mock as mock
        File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\unittest\mock.py", line 26, in <module>
          import asyncio
        File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
          from .base_events import *
        File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 18, in <module>
          import concurrent.futures
        File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9aamtjam\futures_a6a55727fd274809b80a6ed27177b8a9\concurrent\futures\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
          from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
        File "C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9aamtjam\futures_a6a55727fd274809b80a6ed27177b8a9\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 357
          raise type(self._exception), self._exception, self._traceback
                                     ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Does anybody know any workaround?

It seems to me that the `futures` library cannot be installed. When I run it separately, I got the same error.